# How to view the compilation/run time error message

Tags: intellij-idea

New to Intellij IDE, wonder how should I view the compilation/run time error message in detail! It just shows the abstract error message under Build/Event Log.

Should I have to explicitly enable it some where?

Version - Intellij IDEA 2018.3.5(Community Edition)

Comment: How exactly are you compiling your project?

Comment: What is the error displayed and how do you want it to be displayed? Please share some example/screenshot.